# Scrollable property with div positioned at bottom

Tags: html, css

I have an array with texts, which should be displayed in a div. The div has the scrollable property. What I am looking for is that the div shows the bottom and that it can be scrolled up (it must look like a chat). what I am getting is the opposite. The top part appears in the container and I can scroll down.

```
<div id="ionCardMensaje">
 <ElementosMensaje mensajes={msg}></ElementosMensaje>
</div>
```

In the code above, the container should be positioned at the bottom so that it can scroll up.
const ElementosMensaje = (props:{mensajes: Array }) => {
var i=0
return (

{props.mensajes.map((a) => {
i=i+1
return (

)
})
}

)
}

```
const Card = (props:{ usuario:string, mensaje:string, dia:string, hora:string  }) => {
 return(
     <div id="contenedorMensajesChat">
    <IonCard id="cardMensajeChat">
        <p id="p-textoMensaje"> {props.mensaje} </p>
    </IonCard>
    <p id="p-textoMensaje"> {props.dia}+" "+{props.hora} </p>
    </div>
 )
}
```

This is the css

```
#ionCardMensaje{
    overflow: auto;
    height:400px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this.

```
#ionCardMensaje{
    overflow: auto;
    height:400px;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column-reverse;
}
```